# How to get real ip address of website from url behind CloudFlare ip?

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, cloudflare

I am going to find real ip address of website from url. And I am trying to use online service for ip checker (ex : DNSTracker.com). But it is only showing CloudFlare ip address. But I need real ip address. Please help me and any advice is okay for me. Thanks and best regards.

Comment: There's no reliable way to do this, but you can try looking at some of the headers that might be available. Scan down the linked question and see if anything there helps you.

Comment: No, It is not duplicate question. In there, how to get customer ip address. But I want to get website ip address.

Comment: Please check my question, carefully.

Comment: The recommended answer is not correct. You are attempting to identify the IP address behind the Cloudflare proxy. This should be impossible. However, the data might be available from the DNS history, and several websites provide this data. Some Cloudflare users also expose the origin IP through other DNS records, such as when the Website and Email are on the same server. Cloudflare will hide the website address, but cannot hide the IP behind the MX record.